# is it possible to add a webview inside tableRow in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I want to have a list of `WebViews` inside a `TableLayout`, but its not working.

I guess the problem is because the `TableRow` always takes the height of the wrapped contents.
and the `WebView` has a height of zero before it is loaded.

it is mentionned in the TableLayout documentation

> The children of a TableLayout cannot specify the layout_width attribute. Width is always MATCH_PARENT. However, the layout_height attribute can be defined by a child; default value is WRAP_CONTENT. **If the child is a TableRow, then the height is always WRAP_CONTENT**.

Is there a workaround for this?
Is there an application where it is done, just to know if such a thing is possible ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just set the [`minHeight`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aminHeight) and [`minWidth`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aminWidth) to some reasonable values. These values can be either calculated at run-time when activity/fragment is being created, or may be specified in resources so value can be different for different device form-factors.

Comment: Hi, its not working. this works with anything except webview, the webview is simply not showing. although it shows if its a linearlayout